# SQL Oracle missing right parenthesis in count?

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00907

Not sure why it keeps saying missing right parenthesis, it underlines the error at (*) . Please help , thank you.

```
   SELECT FIRST, LAST 
    FROM OFFICERS
    WHERE OFFICER_ID IN (SELECT OFFICER_ID FROM CRIME_OFFICERS COUNT(*) as TotalReportsOfficer                  
    GROUP BY OFFICER_ID

    HAVING TotalReportsOfficer > ((SELECT COUNT(CRIME_ID) from CRIME_OFFICERS))/ (SELECT COUNT(OFFICER_ID) from OFFICERS));
```

> Error:  ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action: Error at Line: 3 Column: 66

Update:
I want to find the number of reports each officer had and than compare each of them to find out which officers had a number that was greater than the average amount of reports.

Comment: maybe there **(SELECT OFFICER_ID FROM CRIME_OFFICERS COUNT(*) as TotalReportsOfficer**

Comment: What do you expect `FROM CRIME_OFFICERS COUNT(*)` to do?

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can use the below query,

```
SELECT OF.FIRST, OF.LAST  FROM OFFICERS OF
    INNER JOIN (SELECT OFFICER_ID, COUNT(*) AS TotalReportsOfficer FROM OFFICERS
    GROUP BY CRIME_OFFICERS) COF
    ON (OF1.OFFICER_ID =COF.OFFICER_ID )
    HAVING COF.TotalReportsOfficer > ((SELECT COUNT(CRIME_ID) from CRIME_OFFICERS)/(SELECT COUNT(OFFICER_ID) from OFFICERS))
```